# Count most frequent test based on criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to pull back the most frequent country based on a sector.

Here is a brief look at the data

[image]

Here is my code:

```
=INDEX(Transactions!$U$2:$U$318,MODE(IF(B5=Transactions!$S$2:$S$318,MATCH(Transactions!$U$2:$U$318,Transactions!$U$2:$U$318,0))))
```

Unfortunately, it appears that since there are multiple countries and multiple sectors in excel, the values pulled back in the Match don't line up with the values in the IF (i.e. IF={1,1,8,5}, MATCH={1,1,289,9})

Can anyone help out with this excel code?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Did you confirm the formula with **CTRL + SHIFT +ENTER** as mentioned [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/most-frequently-occurring-text) at the end of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be: (Confirm with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**)

```
=INDEX(B:B, 10000*MOD(MAX(COUNTIFS(A1:A7,C1,B1:B7,B1:B7)+(ROW(B1:B7)/10000)),1), 1)
```

[image]

The formula is based on the one from [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3351-excel-find-highest-frequency.html) site. I just changed `COUNTIF` to `COUNTIFS` to account for the criteria.